# Struggling with 'quiz' python class logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, numpy, sympy

I have tried search but couldnt find my situation.

I have a function that generates an algebraic equation, a question and an answer. I am attempting to figure out how to pass this to a class. Below is a small part of the code

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self,question,answer=None,equation=None, options=None):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.options = options
        self.equation = equation

    def questionMaker(self):
        pass

def generateLinear1():

    x = sympy.Symbol('x')

    sign1 = random.choice([operator.add,operator.sub])
    sign2 = random.choice([operator.add,operator.sub])

    consts = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(0,4)]

    equation = sympy.Eq(sign1(consts[0]*x,consts[1]) ,sign2(consts[2]*x,consts[3]))

    #Define answers
    answer = sympy.solveset(equation)

    return "Solve for x: %s" % (equation)
```

My end goal is to be able to be able to create a variable via inheritance to then use in the GUI.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I'm not following what you're trying to get help with. Please review [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question.

Comment: Once you have values for question text, answer text, options, and equation, you pass them to the constructor like so: `Question(question, answer, equation, options)`. It looks like `questionMaker` should be a `@classmethod` and do basically what `generateLinear1` does, then create and return a Question instance. E.g. `q = Question.generateLinear()` would give you a Question for a linear equation.

Comment: In general, it helps to first think about your data: what data do you need and what pieces of data you want together. Thinking about the algorithm is easier after that.

Comment: @9000 thank you for your advice. I have around 10 different other functions like generateLinear1 but for all different math functions. What would be the best way to implement this without me putting all the math function code into the class?

Comment: do you want other classes to inherit these functions from a class? or you just want to implement this functions from other class ( to avoid writing same function) ?

Comment: @benjo456: What do you want your `Question` class for? Where and how do you plan to use it? If you already have the functions that generate all the data that a `Question` needs, they could construct and return `Question` instances. `Question` could learn to print itself and check if an answer given to it is correct, etc. If you described your _whole_ task a bit, it would be easier to understand what data structures fit it.

Comment: @9000 the whole project is a maths quiz. There are all different maths topics (e.g. linear algebra, trig) which are made from different functions. I want to use the `Question` class to prevent me having to keep creating new Question functions all the time. Again, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way for you to go at it:

```
class Person(object):
pass


def play():
    print "i'm playing!"



p = Person()
p.play = play
p.play()
```